# ModuleNotFoundError react-native project using Navigation module

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack, codesandbox

ModuleNotFoundError
Could not find module in path: 'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Platform' relative to '/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/processColor.js'

React Native IDE using project ,error display on import  react-navigation